# parsing date using simpleDateFormat java

Tags: java, date, parsing, simpledateformat

I want to parse an String to Date but the date obtained is incorrect. my code is like :

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.S a");
date1 = df.parse("17-DEC-19 05.40.39.364000000 PM");
```

but date1 is: Sat Dec 21 22:47:19 IRST 2019

I need to date: * Dec 17 17:40:39 IRST 2019

Comment: You have an overflow here, i.e. those _milli_ seconds you added are interpreted as 364000 seconds or 4 days 5 hours 6 minutes and 40 seconds. Those are added to the parsed date. Try to add `df.setLenient(false)` and you should get an error.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SimpleDateFormat` does not have precision beyond milliseconds (`.SSS`).

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSS a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date1 = df.parse("17-DEC-19 05.40.39.364 PM");
        System.out.println(date1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Tue Dec 17 17:40:39 GMT 2019
```

Note that the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> .

**Using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        DateTimeFormatter df = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive() // For case-insensitive (e.g. AM/am) parsing
                .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.n a")
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("17-DEC-19 05.40.39.364000000 PM", df);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2019-12-17T17:40:39.364
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>