# Parse RFC3339 Date String 'ss.SSSXX' with BeanIO

Tags: java, date, bean-io, rfc3339

I'm trying to parse a String Date like this: `2021-03-19T13:08:32.58600` with BeanIO in my template:

`<field name="updatedAt" typeHandler="dateTypeHandler" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSSXX"/>`

And I'm getting `Invalid date` error.

I test some cases with SimpleDateFormat and for example, if I do something like this:
`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(text)` it works.

The problem is in `DateTypeHandlerSupport` class, the method parse validate the length:

```
    protected Date parseDate(String text) throws TypeConversionException {
        if ("".equals(text))
            return null;

        ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
        Date date = getFormat().parse(text, pp);
        if (pp.getErrorIndex() >= 0 || pp.getIndex() != text.length()) {
            throw new TypeConversionException("Invalid date");
        }
        return date;
    }
```

Is there any way which I could parse the string without creating my own DateTypeHandler?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. It’s not completely clear to me whether you will need `LocalDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`, though. Both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trailing `00` of your string is not a valid UTC offset. I am pretty convinced that it was never meant to be one. Rather your string gives us seconds with a decimal fraction of 5 digits and does not include an offset.

And I am sorry, you cannot parse that. If BeanIO internally uses `SimpleDateFormat` (a notorious troublemaker of a class, fortunately long outdated), then there is no way it can parse `2021-03-19T13:08:32.58600` correctly. `SimpleDateFormat` supports only exactly three decimals of fraction on the seconds and will parse `.58600` as 58600 milliseconds, that is, 58.6 seconds (that’s correct). See the links to related questions at the bottom.

Also your string does not conform to RFC-3339. According to RFC-3339 a timestamp must include a `time-offset` which must be either of `"Z" / time-numoffset`, where `time-numoffset` is `("+" / "-") time-hour ":" time-minute`. So examples of valid offsets include `Z`, `+00:00`, `+11:00`, `-00:00` and `-11:00`. If you have received that string as RFC-3339 from somewhere, it seems that you need to educate the publisher about that format standard.

Parsing your string in Java is easy.

```
    String yourString = "2021-03-19T13:08:32.58600";
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(yourString);
    System.out.println(ldt);
```

Output:

> 2021-03-19T13:08:32.586

The classes of java.time parse the most common variants of ISO 8601 format as their default, that is, without any specification of the format. RFC-3339 is based on ISO 8601 and is simplified compared to it. Since your string did not include UTC offset, I parsed into a `LocalDateTime`, which the class for a date and time without time zone or UTC offset.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Related questions:

  - [parsing date using simpleDateFormat java [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66812017/parsing-date-using-simpledateformat-java).
  - [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z' format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000755/yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssssssz-format).
- [Request for Comments: 3339: Date and Time on the Internet: Timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#page-4).

Answer (score 1):

I know the current version (2.1) doesn't support the new `java.time` classes out of the box, but it will be in the [new BeanIO project](https://github.com/beanio/beanio), which got new life.

While we wait for the new version to support `java.time` out of the box, you can implement it yourself relatively easy by creating your own `org.beanio.types.TypeHandler` implementation, most likely by implementing `org.beanio.types.ConfigurableTypeHandler`. You can view the [new TemporalAccessorTypeHandler implementation](https://github.com/beanio/beanio/blob/main/src/org/beanio/types/ConfigurableTypeHandler.java) and use it to roll your own for the time being until you can upgrade to the latest version. This [discussion](https://github.com/beanio/beanio/discussions/137) also shows how you can use this type handler and to configure it.

I'm not going to copy the code for the `TemporalAccessorTypeHandler` here but you can configure it this way:

```
// declare/register your new type handler
<typeHandler name="javaTimeTypeHandler" 
    class="path.to.your.implementation.TemporalAccessorTypeHandler" />


// now use it in your fields
<field name="updatedAt" typeHandler="javaTimeTypeHandler" 
    format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSSXX"/>
```